# Change nodejs command to node on debian

Tags: bash, debian

Please don't down vote, newbie here...
I'm new to node js. I installed it using apt utility. But I cannot run the interpreter using node command. Instead I have to use nodejs app.js to run. Is this okay to do it this way and how can I fix this? I'm using Debian Jessie

Comment: I thought they would have fixed that - there's an unrelated, older, and less popular package that had that name first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a symbolic link /usr/bin/node.

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

It's the same things to do in Debian.

Comment: Tried to vote up your answer but I guess I don't have enough privileges right now.